# Build Eclipse C++ project in terminal

Tags: compiling, eclipse-cdt, xilinx

We have an Eclipse C++ project (.project & .cproject) which has to be build from the *Xilinx SDK GUI*.

How can this project be built from the command line?
This is required for an automated build.

Our Xilinx SDK version is 2016.3.
Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "batch mode". Batch mode description can be found here: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2014_3/SDK_Doc/concepts/sdk_c_batch_mode.htm#50655672_26190